# C# Nested MySqlConnections

Tags: c#, mysql, loops, nested, datareader

I am used to programming in PHP which makes me nest SQL-query strings with ease. However, with C#, I am finding it difficult. The connections seems to get maxed (I get user_max_connections error). So I am wondering if I can somehow store the data from the DataReader so that I can close the connection, and then loop through the array/table/w.e. How do I do this?

I am right now doing **while (rdr.Read()) {}**. Then inside this while-loop I have a couple just like it. This makes me forced to have several connections open <- PROBLEM!

I cannot combine the SQL-queries either. So can I somehow during **while (rdr.Read()) {}** store all the data in an array or something? Then close the connection. Then loop trough the new array instead of the DataReader?

Would appreciate your thoughts soooo much!

Comment: Don't do that ! Simple and easy it is bad practise. Open()-> Close() connection after not need it anymore. After that open another connection and so on.

Comment: Please post a full example, I have a feeling you are not properly closing connections after you are finished using them.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g7q5UEJ2

Sorry for the delay

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new connection for each command,  use one connection.

Comment: If I do this I get an error telling me that I am already using that connection. Although, I did end up refining the MySQL-query on this function. However, I do have the same problem on a different function. I'll post it too. http://pastebin.com/X88K6F5D

Comment: This is never a good idea. You don't have to create a connection each time you send command also. Have you tried `join` in SQL to get the table you want at once?